# Using CSS3 Pie with jQuery BlockUI

Tags: jquery, css, css3pie, blockui, jquery-blockui

I am using [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for doing cross browser border-radius and box-shadows. This works really great. But when used together with the jQuery [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin (using modal dialogs), CSS3 Pie functionality does not apply to that dialog element.

This is because of the z-index problem with position:fixed , which is also described [here](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/). I already tried to change position to relative on the target element, played arround with the z-index, but it won´t work.

Maybe someone of you had a similar problem and can help me out here

Comment: I guess that's the risk of using these techniques to get IE to do something it doesn't want to.. good luck

Comment: when you say it stops working, do you mean that it breaks all the CSS3Pie elements on the page, or just the ones related to blickUI?

Comment: only the related dialog, which is produced by the jquery plugin (i adapted my question to be more precise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of CSS3Pie are you using?

I don't know how blockUI works, but it is possible that it hides its pop-up elements off the top of the screen or something like that while they're not being used.

If that's the case, and if you're using the first version of CSS3Pie (beta 1), there was a bug in that version which threw a Javascript error when it tried to access an element with a negative position. This bug has been fixed in beta 2.

If you're using beta 1, you should go back to the CSS3Pie site and install beta 2.

Finally, have you asked on the CSS3Pie site -- the forums are fairly active, and the developer answers a lot of questions himself.

If it still doesn't work, I believe he's getting quite close to releasing a third beta version fairly soon.

Comment: thanks, i asked the question on their forums. and i am using beta2